# Discord bot, how to check for user before executing task

Tags: discord, discord.js

So im trying to make a personal bot for severs which does my deeds, but i cant check for the user

My code is in the following :

```
       if(!message.author.username === ('>.<')) {
            message.channel.send('You aint my master! ._.');
            return;
        }else if(!mentionMember) {
            message.channel.send('You forgot to mention the user you idiot');
            return;
        };
```

But when running the command the bot executes another line of code and the ouput is the following :

```
You forgot to mention the user you idiot
```

This isnt the intended output and i dont know whats wrong with it

please assist
thank you :)

Comment: How is `mentionMember` defined?

Comment: @Lioness100 i dont know what you mean? i have no idea how it is defined. please explain

Comment: I mean what is `???` in `const mentionMember === ???`

Comment: i have defined it in a different way: `let mentionMember = message.mentions.members.first();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your username? Mind you ('>.<') is parsed as `>.<`, You should be using "('>.<')" if those brackets are in your username,

Also you used `!message.author.username === ('>.<')`, Lets assume your username is `>.<`,
`!message.author.username` was interpreted as `false` (since the negation of a string is false)
and `false` and `>.<` are not equal therefore the first statement was interpreted as `false`.

What you are looking for is

```
if(message.author.username !== '>.<') {
            message.channel.send('You aint my master! ._.');
            return;
        }else if(!mentionMember) {
            message.channel.send('You forgot to mention the user you idiot');
            return;
        };
```

Furthermore using usernames is a very very BAD idea, since anyone can change the username to yours, use discord user ids. Copy your user ID (You need developer mode to be turned on)

[image: Copy User ID]

and use `message.author.id === "1234567890"`, where `1234567890` is your id.

so Finally this is what you should be doing:

```
if(message.author.id!== "1234567890") {
            message.channel.send('You aint my master! ._.');
            return;
        }else if(!mentionMember) {
            message.channel.send('You forgot to mention the user you idiot');
            return;
        };
```

Comment: my username is >.< but ill give arthur id a try
edit: unfoutntanly arthur id doesnt fix the problem, and if you have any suggestion please explain

Comment: Oh btw !"Any string" == false, I think What you mean't to do is !(username === "this") or better username !== "this"

Comment: u want me to change the code? i dont quite understand how that would help me. oh wait you just editied it nevermind

Comment: please put this into an answer as i cant make much sense out of it as im new to discord.js or js in general

Comment: lemme add that to the answer

Comment: ok, thanks for the edited answer but i still dont understand how i should change it. should i put the rest of my kick command into the if and remove the `!` and have a else at the end which has my error message?

Comment: it works thank you very much. i still have many functions to add, and if you are interested can you help me work on my bot?you sound like someone who know how to code stuff my discord is >.<#4907 if you are intersted